# vibrate issue on ringer mode RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, vibration

I have an issue with an application: even if ringer mode is `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE` and vibrate setting is `VIBRATE_SETTING_ON`, my phone does not vibrate. Here is my code:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
```

Note: I am using this code in a broadcast receiver, when the device is ringing (state is `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`)

THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you set on the permission in the manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATOR" />
```

Comment: you were right, adding this permission fixed my issue. But can you please explain to me why? I had permission "android.permission.VIBRATE" and "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS", why do I need this permission?

Comment: I'm not sure either :)